# Leray-Hirsch statement Theorem explanation

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

This is on [p50 Bott & Tu's Differential Forms](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf)

> (Leray-Hirsch) Let $E$ be a fiber bundle over $M$ with fiber $F$. Suppose $M$ has a finite good cover. If there are global cohomology classes $e_1, \ldots, e_r$ on $E$ which when restricted to each fiber freely generate the cohomology of the fiber, then $H^*(E)$ is a free module over $H^*(M)$. 
>   $$H^*(E) \cong H^*(M) \otimes \Bbb R \{e_1, \ldots, e_r \} \cong H^*(M) \otimes H^*(F)$$

I am unsure - **but does the hypothesis implies $E \cong M \times F$ as fiber bundles?**

---

Here we have fiber space $F = \Bbb R^n$, in which our topological group $G$ that acts freely on $F$ is $GL_n(\Bbb R)$.

Then there is a map 
$$ M \times F \rightarrow E, \quad (m,v) \mapsto \sum v_i e_i (m)$$ 
where $\sum v_i e_i(m)$ is in the fiber of $m$. The map is an isomorphism as restricted to each map, it is an $\Bbb R$-linear continuous isomoprhism. And as a general result of topological vector bundles, this is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.

Firstly, a fibre bundle is a much more general object than a vector bundle, which is just a fibre bundle with typical fibre a vector space, that satisfies some additional conditions.

Note that your example is incorrect. In general there is no such map, since you are relying on the existence of a collection $(e_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ of global non-vanishing sections $M\rightarrow E$. Such a collection exists if and only if the bundle is trivial. If the bundle is trivial, then the map you write down is indeed a global trivialisation, providing the bundle isomorphism $E\cong M\times \mathbb{R}^n$. Conversely, if $\varphi:M\times F\xrightarrow{\cong} E$ is a global trivialisation, then the $n$ maps $e_i:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $m\mapsto \varphi(m,v_i)$, where $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector, are a collection of $n$ non-vanishing global sections.

In general there do exist non-trivial vector bundles. For instance, the Möbius bundle $E\rightarrow S^1$. You can check quite easily that there are no sections $S^1\rightarrow E$ that do no vanish at at least one point of $S^1$.

As an example of a fibre bundle meeting the assumptions of the Leray-Hirsch theorem you state, consider the bundle

$$S^2\xrightarrow{i}\mathbb{C}P^3\xrightarrow{p} S^4.$$

Here you have

$$H^*\mathbb{C}P^3\cong \mathbb{Z}[x_2]/(x_2^4)\cong \{1,x_2\}\otimes H^*S^4\cong H^*S^2\otimes H^*S^4$$

where $i^*x_2=s_2\in H^2S^2$ is a generator, and for a generator $s_4\in H^4S^4$, it holds that $p^*s_4=x_2^2\in H^4\mathbb{C}P^3$.

Comment: What is $p$ in the fiber bundle you mentioned? BTW is  there  what is  an example of  a  fiber bundle which meet  lery hirsch theorem but it is neither trivial nor its fiber is  a   real or complex projective  space. in your example each fiber is $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I wrote a little more about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294581/a-gluing-construction-for-complex-projective-space/3294653#3294653) (although I denoted by $\pi$ the map $p$).

Comment: @AliTaghavi, the bundles $SU_n\rightarrow SU_{n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n+1}$ for any coefficients. In fact I just checked and Hatcher discusses this example and more in his book.