# Hatcher's proof of Leray–Hirsch theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

[image]

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. I think the definition of $\Phi$ relies on the assumption (b), but the  left and right $\Phi$ from the commutative diagram don't have such an assumption. I wonder how is the left and right $\Phi$ defined? In particular, for the element $b\otimes i^*(c_j)\in H^*(B')\otimes H^*(F)$, I think $c_j$ here is from $H^{k_j}(E',R)$, but do we have $i^*(c_j)$, where $c_j\in H^{k_j}(E',R)$, form a basis for $H^*(F,R)$?
2. Why do we have $\delta c_j=0$? I think $c_j\in H^{k_j}(E,R)$ and $\delta:H^{k_j}(E')\to H^{k_j+1}(E,E')$, and I don't know how the $\delta$ act on $c_j$ and why is $p^*(b)\smile c_j\in H^*(E')$ s.t. $\delta c_j=0$.
3. About the claim that "The theorem for finite-dimensional $B$ will now follow by INDUCTION on $n$ and the five-lemma once we show that the left-hand $\Phi$ in the diagram is an isomorphism."  I wonder for the 'induction' above means that: by $B'$ can be deformation retracted to a lower dimension CW-complex, we can use the induction so that the right $\Phi:H^*(B')\otimes H^*(F)\to H^*(E')$ is an isomorphism? And if so, then my first question arises again: i.e. for the case of $B',E'$, we don't have the assumption (b), then how do we apply the induction?

Some thoughts: I wonder if the property (b) works for the fiber bundle $F\to E'\to B'$? i.e. I wonder if there exist classes $c_j\in H^{k_j}(E'; R)$ whose restrictions $i^*(c_j)$ form a basis for $H^*(F; R)$ in each fiber $F$, where $i:F\to E$ is the inclusion. Then the map $$\Phi: H^*(B'; R)\otimes_RH^*(F;R)\to H^*(E'; R), \sum_{ij} b_i\otimes_R i^*(c_j)\mapsto \sum_{ij} p^*(b_i)\smile c_j,$$ is an isomorphism of $R$ modules?

Comment: Hatcher states "The map $\Phi$ on the left is defined exactly as in the absolute case, using the relative cup product". You still need the classes $c_j$ and it is defined in exactly the same way, only replacing the $b_i$ with relative classes. Similarly for the $\Phi$ on the right.

Comment: I think the $\delta$ you refer to is the coboundary $\delta:H^*E'\rightarrow H^{*+1}(E,E')$? If $c_j$ comes from $H^* E$ then $\delta c_j=0$ by exactness of the bottom row.

Comment: @Tyrone thanks for the explanation, I have one more question. For the isomorphism $\Phi$, it's an isomorphism of $R$-algebras, right?

Comment: The isomorphism is *not* one of $R$-algebras. The isomorphism as stated by Hatcher is only one of $R$-modules. However you do get the stronger result that it's actually one of $H^*(B)$-modules, where $H^*(E)$ gets its $H^*(B)$-algebra structure through the map $p^*$.

Comment: To see an example of where the isomorphism fails to be one of $R$-algebras consider the fibration sequence $S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^3\rightarrow S^4$ 
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294581/a-gluing-construction-for-complex-projective-space/3294653#3294653) for more info). Then $H^*CP^3\cong\mathbb{Z}[x_2]/(x_2^4)$ is a truncated polynomial algebra but $H^*S^2\otimes H^*S^4\cong \Lambda(s_2,s_4)$ is an exterior algebra.